# jQuery file upload user directories

Tags: jquery, upload, customization

I try to use my own directories in order to upload files into them but an error occurs when I load my page "upload_test.php"

```
userPath is not defined
```

I've been trying many solutions for 2 days but none worked :(

Here is my code for this page

```
<form id="fileupload" action="UploadHandler.php?userPath=<?php echo $MYDIR;?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here is my code in main.js

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'file_upload/server/php/index.php?userPath='+userPath,
});
```

and for index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

protected function get_user_id() {
    return $_REQUEST['userPath'];
}

protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
  $file->deleteUrl = $this->options['script_url']
    .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
    .$this->get_singular_param_name()
    .'='.rawurlencode($file->name)
    .'&userPath='.$_REQUEST['userPath']
    ;
  $file->deleteType = $this->options['delete_type'];
  if ($file->deleteType !== 'DELETE') {
    $file->deleteUrl .= '&_method=DELETE';
  }
  if ($this->options['access_control_allow_credentials']) {
    $file->deleteWithCredentials = true;
  }
 }   

}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(array(
'user_dirs' => true,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would amend the get_user_id() function as following:

```
protected function get_user_id() {
    return array_key_exists('userPath', $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST['userPath'] : '';
}
```

You get a NOTICE message from the PHP interpreter because it is not guaranteed that the userPath key will always exist.

Every time you interact with arrays, e.g. the $_REQUEST array, you need to prepare your app to deal with the case, that the particular key does not exist, otherwise you will get a NOTICE message, like the one you got above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Indeed, it works better!
However, uploaded files do not save to my custom folder and only files directly under the files folder are visible.
I think UploadHandler ignores my custom folder.

Comment: Can you please check the followings: - Does the folder have the proper file permissions? - Does the folder exist where you want to put the files? - Do you have the right to create new folders?

Comment: Everything is good on this side. My folder is created and the permissions are ok.
I tried changing this in main.js to test:
    url: 'file_upload/server/php/index.php?userPath=MYDIR'
and it works.
But I would like to use a parameter (of course !)